# jQuery toggleClass not working as expected

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

The following toggleClass does not work:

```
    $nav_item = $ ('.active_wrapper, .main_nav div.arrow_up_img, .main_nav div.arrow_down_img'),
    $arrow_down = $ ('.main_nav div.arrow_down_img'),
    $arrow_up = $ ('main_nav div.arrow_up_img');

    $('.active_wrapper').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.main_nav div').not($nav_item).slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $(arrow_down).toggleClass($arrow_up);
        });

    });
```

HTML

```
        <nav class="main_nav">
            <div class="active_wrapper"><a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="arrow_down_img"></div>
            </div>
            <div><a href="about.php">About Us</a></div> 
            <div><a href="flavours.php">Flavours</a></div>
            <div><a href="stockists.php">Stockists</a></div>
            <div><a href="thecollective.php">The collective</a></div>
            <div><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></div>
        </nav>
```

The toggleClass is used to swap between 2 arrows one pointing up and one down (you can imagine this is a drop down menu) but I really can't figure out why it is not working..

Comment: You are passing jQuery object instead of a class. Additionally the selector for arrow_up is not correct, so you are passing an empty jQuery object

Comment: is this correct than? $('.main_nav div.arrow_down_img').toggleClass('main_nav div.arrow_up_img');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code would be
`$arrow_down.toggleClass('arrow_up_img');`

Comment: still not working, I have tried to put an alert box to see if the callback function works and it does, so it means there is something wrong I can't figure it out :(

Comment: Hi just checked the HTML and the class 'arrow_up_img' gets added, however $arrow_down is still there.. I need to swap between the 2

Comment: then you have to toggle both of them: `$arrow_down.toggleClass('arrow_up_img').toggleClass('arrow_down_img');`

Answer (score 0):

```
   nav_item = $ ('.active_wrapper, .main_nav div.arrow_up_img, .main_nav div.arrow_down_img');
   arrow_down = $ ('.main_nav div.arrow_down_img');//missing semi colon
   arrow_up = $('main_nav div.arrow_up_img');//missing semi colon

$('.active_wrapper').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.main_nav div').not(nav_item).slideToggle('slow', function(){
        arrow_down.toggleClass(arrow_up);//Invalid Object assignment
    });

});​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4QCHF/2/)